# Fetch only embedded document using Query or Agreegation doesn't work well

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I've multiple addresses in my collection and I want to fetch all those, How can I do that ? I tried below, but it doesn't worked well.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("Address");
List<Address> list1 = template.find(query, Address.class);
System.out.println(list1);
```

Here is the collection

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("592c7029aafef820f432c5f3"),
  "_class" : "lankydan.tutorial.mongodb.documents.Person",
  "firstName" : "John",
  "secondName" : "Doe",
  "dateOfBirth" : ISODate("2017-05-29T20:02:01.636+01:00"),
  "address" : [
      {
        "addressLineOne" : "19 Imaginary Road",
        "addressLineTwo" : "Imaginary Place",
        "city" : "Imaginary City",
        "country" : "US"
      },
      {
        "addressLineOne" : "22 South Road",
        "addressLineTwo" : "South Place",
        "city" : "CA",
        "country" : "US"
      }
    ],
  "profession" : "Winner",
  "salary" : 100,
  "hobbies" : [ 
    {
      "name" : "Badminton"
    }, 
    {
      "name" : "TV"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below works well, but I loose the findAll() method for User collection. How to fill this gap ?

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{_id : 0, address:1}")
List<User> findAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `_id` from `query fields` by adding the `exclude` operator in `query` as below:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.fields().include("Address").exclude("_id");
List<Address> list1 = template.find(query, Address.class);

System.out.println(list1);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.